# MongoDB and Redis: how do you estimate the size of the overhead?

Tags: database, mongodb, redis, overhead, memory-overhead

Does someone of you know how much overhead Redis and MongoDB produce in the context of storing images? I'd be thankful for some insights or if you even have a reliable source where I can look that up.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, it depends on lots of parameters, that you should specify.

Answer (score 0):

> how do you estimate the size of the overhead?

Create a new deployment, store your images, calculate the total size occupied by the deployment, subtract the size of your images.

The database system itself uses some disk for internal bookkeeping thus the overhead you calculate in this way would in fact be an *estimate* of the overhead of image storage. Store more data to make this estimate more accurate.